# The keys on my microsoft natural ergonomic 400 keyboard are very loud, is there a way to adjust the key pad noise?

Tags: keyboard, noise, ergonomics

I use it docked to an MS Surface when in my home office. All of the keys are loud / noisy, not just the space bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The key clicks are purely mechanical. There is no volume control.

Answer (score 0):

My mechanical keyboard makes no noise to 'click' the keys but makes a LOT of noise when I bottom them out on the deck.

This doesn't bother me and there is no one nearby me to be bother either so I don't worry about it.

But, if I wanted to keep it quieter, there are a couple of choices that to consider: 1) teach myself to type without fully depressing the keys or at least to do so much softer 2) pull the keyboard keys and put a thin cushioning layer between the keys and the deck. A layer of cotton fabric will do a lot, or that thin rubber drawer liner that is available at home improvement centers